# Does anyone know a base64 website decoder?

Tags: web, base64

I knew some time ago a website like (example):

https://base64decode/*?VGVzdA==*

All you had to do was put the encoded code after the "?"

And it returns on blank page with only the decoded text "Test".
Does anyone know this site?

Sorry if I'm expressing myself badly, I don't really have the words to explain.
Thank you.

Comment: Since it's a GET request, I suppose it will not work well with some really big inputs.

Comment: All base64 decoders online I know perform the conversion directly using a javascript library. I have never saw a site that performs such conversion using GET http request.

Answer (score 0):

It's working as expected.
UTF-8 equivalent of **VGVzdA==** is actually **Test**

You can validate using custom code. Please refer to the sample code that I wrote [here on JS.do](https://js.do/sgrpwr/base64encoderdecoder)

Comment: Hi I think you misunderstood, my bad, "VGVzdA==" was an example, I just want a website that does what I described.
btw: no code appears on the site you sent me.
Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @Tibo1211 Hmm my bad... Can you click on link one more time?